# Mongo - Fetch first created and last created document according to 'ts' (timestamp)

Tags: php, mongodb

Is it possible to fetch first created and last created document according to 'ts' (timestamp) element of the document in single mongo query?
If yes then please let me know how to query the mongo using php.

Answer (score 8):

You can't get them in one query, but you can do it in 2 queries.

```
db.collection.find().limit(1).sort([ts:-1])  --> Find the last timestampe
db.collection.find().limit(1).sort([ts:1])   --> Find the first timestamp
```

or in PHP

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array('ts'=>-1))->limit(1);
$cursor = $collection=>find()->sort(array('ts'=>1))->limit(1);
```

Comment: The queries in Mongo should be:
`db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({ts:-1})  --> Find the last timestamp` and 
`db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({ts:1})   --> Find the first timestamp`